# Flutter plugin for automated emails?

Tags: android, library, ios, email, dart

Searched everywhere and couldn’t really find a solution to this. Is there a flutter plugin for sending automated emails in the background (ie without opening email app and having user hit send)? Basically I’d like to be able to pass a sender email, receiver email, subject, body, attachments, etc.

I know plugins such as:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mailer
exist but I don't believe they allow for a custom sender email.

If this plugin doesn’t exist yet, how could one go about building it? I would love to build it out if possible and publish it. Any guidance here is appreciated, thanks! :-)

edit:  https://pub.dev/packages/mailer is what i needed

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (also [see here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)) – but answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question-post. Mind [edit]ing that out of your question, and move it to a separate answer – with a few more details what makes that package fit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the info ! Could you please post an answer and accept it? t may take two days before the system allows you to accept your own answer. Doing so will help others who read this question in future (I know that you give the answer in the question, but anyone searching will see this as a question with no answers & might not read it.